# How do I replace the actual chain part of the ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I probably need to buy a new switch but I can't figure out how to take out the chain of the old one. I have a housing that separates the bottom of the chain, with its round piece that you pull on, from the top of the chain, which goes into the switch.

The problem is that the housing only has a little hole separating the ends which neither end would fit through without taking off the switch or the round pull thing, and I can't see how to do that. How do I do this?

Also, the new switches come with a small bit of chain. How would I connect the old chain with the original end piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain is integral to the switch.   You do not reuse your old chain, the new switch comes with one.

If it won't fit through the hole, that is an extension on your chain.  Look carefully mid-chain for a place to separate it.

Comment: I can not find a connector. Here are two pictures of the top and bottom of the chain with overlap: http://imgur.com/go6uknn http://imgur.com/REbthJr Could it be that the end was crimped on to the end of the chain after it was through?

Comment: Nevermind. The extension was on the end, after the circle pull tab.